# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am creating a web application which will run on a local machine. I am trying to write code on the print button.

While initializing new `PosExplorer()` I get the error:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception.".
>
> In the inner exception: "This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch."

I have installed microsoft POS for .net 1.12 and have also tried using  `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"` in the `web.config` as well as `devenv.exe.config` file, but none of them resolved my issue.

I am using vs 2010.

Any help will be highly thanked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding

```
<runtime>
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

in to the path
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe

And restart the development environment.
Thanks