# Unable to connect to Stratos 2700 scale/scanner

Tags: vb.net, port, hyperterminal

I have a problem connecting to the scale/scanner HoneyWell Stratos 2700. I'm using the library HHP provided by Honeywell and need an XML file to configure it, however I can't connect to the scale/scanner.

I am using this code:

```
Public Class Form1

   Private WithEvents mScanner As New HHP.PointOfService.ServiceObjects.Scanner.HandHeldScanner
   Private WithEvents mScale As New HHP.PointOfService.ServiceObjects.ScaleSO.HWScaleSO

   Private str As String
   Public Sub reader()

   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Try

         mScanner.Open()

         mScanner.AssignLogicalname = "scannerABC"

         If (mScanner.State = 1) Then
         End If


      Catch excp As Exception
         Console.WriteLine(excp.Message)
      End Try

   End Sub
End Class
```

I am receiving this error message:

> "Exception type 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978821/the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-pointofservice-management-explorer-threw-an)

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: Se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo de 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer'.